# How do you run scheduled tasks with extra parameters in Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, g-suite

The issue that we are facing now is that Scheduled Synchronization is not working when the task scheduler executes a program for Google Apps.

The program runs as follows when within command prompt:

CD C:\Program Files\Google Apps Directory Sync\

sync-cmd.exe -a -o -c August2011.xml

We are running Windows Server 2008 so the referenced link does not really apply (http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/admin/en/gads/admin/sync_schedule.html)

We've tried the following in the Windows Task Scheduler with not much luck:

Program/Script: "sync-cmd.exe -a -o -c August2011.xml"
Add Arguments:
Start in: "C:\Program Files\Google Apps Directory Sync\"

Program/Script: "C:\Program Files\Google Apps Directory Sync\sync-cmd.exe"
Add Arguments: "-a -o -c August2011.xml"
Start in:

Program/Script: "C:\Program Files\Google Apps Directory Sync\sync-cmd.exe" -a -o -c August2011.xml
Add Arguments:
Start in:

Which is correct? I wish there was just an advanced button as Google's documentation mentions. I look forward to some assistance on this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried placing the two commands "cd" and "sync-cmd.exe" into a batch (.bat) file, then scheduling the batch file to execute?